# How to get list out of list in python?

Tags: python, list

Is there any way to remove double list? Right now I have a list inside a list as an output.

```
target_rule = [ '2.1.1 Context','2.1.2.4 Helping Us out','We know that']
target=[]
x=[s for s in target_rule if re.findall("\d",s)]

if x:  
    target.append(x)
print(target)
```

Output is

```
[['2.1.1 Context', '2.1.2.4 Helping Us out']]
```

But I want the output to be

```
['2.1.1 Context', '2.1.2.4 Helping Us out']
```

Comment: why are you using `target` instead of just using `x`? or say, `target = x` ?

Comment: remove `if` conditions and just `print (x)`

Comment: Alternately, if there's a reason you have to return this in a nested fashion, you can unnest it one level by indexing into the first element: `target[0]`

Comment: You can just replace ``target.append(x)`` with ``target.extend(x)``.

Comment: The simple solution is to just ```print(x)``` since x is the already a list because of the list comprehension expression
```
x=[s for s in target_rule if re.findall("\d",s)]
```


However, If you want to continuously do this and that ```target``` is an array you want to continuously add to in this fashion

Well one solution would be to just iterate and append each element

```
if x:
    for (element in x){
        target.append(element)
    }

```
Or you can use list append 
```
target+=x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
target_rule = [ '2.1.1 Context','2.1.2.4 Helping Us out','We know that']
x=[s for s in target_rule if re.findall("\d",s)]

print(x)
```

x here is already a list because of the comprehension in line 3

in your code, target was redundant because you were appending a list to a list. If you would like to have a separate variable to return/print you can do

```
target = x
return target
```